# How to add an object to array on base of text box value within ng-click action

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

How to add a Technology, which is entered in the text box as a record when i click on add button in ng-click action required for my table?

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope){
$scope.technologies = [
  {name:'C#', likes:'0', dislikes:'0'},
  {name:'.Net', likes:'0', dislikes:'0'},
  {name:'Java', likes:'0', dislikes:'0'},
  {name:'MySQL', likes:'0', dislikes:'0'}
  ];

  $scope.incrementlikes = function(technology){
  technology.likes++;
  }
  $scope.incrementdislikes = function(technology){
  technology.dislikes++;
  }
  $scope.addRecord = function(text){
  $scope.technology.push({name:text, likes:'0', dislikes:'0'});
  }
});
```

```css
table,
th,
tr,
td {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  background: #006688;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <table style="width:400px;">
    <tr>
      <td align="right">Enter Technologies : </td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="Add" ng-click="addRecord(technology);" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table style="width:400px;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Likes</th>
        <th>Dislikes</th>
        <th>Likes / Dislikes</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="technology in technologies">
        <td>{{technology.name}}</td>
        <td align="center">{{technology.likes}}</td>
        <td align="center">{{technology.dislikes}}</td>
        <td align="center">
          <input type="button" value="Likes" ng-click="incrementlikes(technology);" />
          <input type="button" value="Dislikes" ng-click="incrementdislikes(technology);" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: In 'addRecord' method, try to push into `$scope.technologies`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `ng-model` to your input to accept some name for a *technology*. Then add a record with an object, e.g. `addRecord({'name':name,'likes':0,'dislikes':0})`. This should populate the existing array with push: `$scope.technologies.push(technology);`.

Here is a demo:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.technologies = [{
      name: 'C#',
      likes: '0',
      dislikes: '0'
    },
    {
      name: '.Net',
      likes: '0',
      dislikes: '0'
    },
    {
      name: 'Java',
      likes: '0',
      dislikes: '0'
    },
    {
      name: 'MySQL',
      likes: '0',
      dislikes: '0'
    }
  ];

  $scope.incrementlikes = function(technology) {
    technology.likes++;
  }
  $scope.incrementdislikes = function(technology) {
    technology.dislikes++;
  }
  $scope.addRecord = function(technology) {
    $scope.technologies.push(technology);
  }
});
```

```css
table,
th,
tr,
td {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  background: #006688;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <table style="width:400px;">
    <tr>
      <td align="right">Enter Technologies : </td>
      <td><input type="text" ng-model="name" /></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="Add" ng-click="addRecord({'name':name,'likes':0,'dislikes':0});" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table style="width:400px;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Likes</th>
        <th>Dislikes</th>
        <th>Likes / Dislikes</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="technology in technologies">
        <td>{{technology.name}}</td>
        <td align="center">{{technology.likes}}</td>
        <td align="center">{{technology.dislikes}}</td>
        <td align="center">
          <input type="button" value="Likes" ng-click="incrementlikes(technology);" />
          <input type="button" value="Dislikes" ng-click="incrementdislikes(technology);" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In angular is not needed to pass the parameter. You can use angular data binding to write directly into the controller's variable like so

Cotroller

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.newTech = {
      name: '',
      likes: '0',
      dislikes: '0'
  };

  $scope.technologies = [{
      name: 'C#',
      likes: '0',
      dislikes: '0'
    },
    {
      name: '.Net',
      likes: '0',
      dislikes: '0'
    },
    {
      name: 'Java',
      likes: '0',
      dislikes: '0'
    },
    {
      name: 'MySQL',
      likes: '0',
      dislikes: '0'
    }
  ];

  $scope.incrementlikes = function(technology) {
    technology.likes++;
  }
  $scope.incrementdislikes = function(technology) {
    technology.dislikes++;
  }
  $scope.addRecord = function(technology) {
    $scope.technologies.push(newTech);
    newTech.name = ''; // reset variable
  }
});
```

Markup

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <table style="width:400px;">
    <tr>
      <td align="right">Enter Technologies : </td>
      <td><input type="text" ng-model="newTech.name" /></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="Add" ng-click="addRecord();" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table style="width:400px;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Likes</th>
        <th>Dislikes</th>
        <th>Likes / Dislikes</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="technology in technologies">
        <td>{{technology.name}}</td>
        <td align="center">{{technology.likes}}</td>
        <td align="center">{{technology.dislikes}}</td>
        <td align="center">
          <input type="button" value="Likes" ng-click="incrementlikes(technology);" />
          <input type="button" value="Dislikes" ng-click="incrementdislikes(technology);" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is working code you need to use ng-model on your input field to get value from that text box and initialize in controller and then push it in $scope.technologies.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.formData = {};
  $scope.technologies = [{
      name: 'C#',
      likes: '0',
      dislikes: '0'
    },
    {
      name: '.Net',
      likes: '0',
      dislikes: '0'
    },
    {
      name: 'Java',
      likes: '0',
      dislikes: '0'
    },
    {
      name: 'MySQL',
      likes: '0',
      dislikes: '0'
    }
  ];

  $scope.incrementlikes = function(technology) {
    technology.likes++;
  }
  $scope.incrementdislikes = function(technology) {
    technology.dislikes++;
  }
  $scope.addRecord = function() {
    $scope.formData.likes = 0;
    $scope.formData.dislikes = 0;
    $scope.technologies.push($scope.formData);
  }
});
```

```css
table,
th,
tr,
td {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  background: #006688;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <table style="width:400px;">
    <tr>
      <td align="right">Enter Technologies : </td>
      <td><input type="text" ng-model="formData.name"/></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="Add" ng-click="addRecord(technology);" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table style="width:400px;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Likes</th>
        <th>Dislikes</th>
        <th>Likes / Dislikes</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="technology in technologies">
        <td>{{technology.name}}</td>
        <td align="center">{{technology.likes}}</td>
        <td align="center">{{technology.dislikes}}</td>
        <td align="center">
          <input type="button" value="Likes" ng-click="incrementlikes(technology);" />
          <input type="button" value="Dislikes" ng-click="incrementdislikes(technology);" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `newTechName` variable in controller. Bind it to text field.

```
<td><input type="text" ng-model=newTechName></td>
```

Now you can use it in `addRecord`:

```
$scope.addRecord = function() {
   var technology = {likes: '0', dislikes: '0'};
   technology.name = $scope.newTechName;
   $scope.technologies.push(technology);
}
```

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  
    $scope.newTechName = '';
    $scope.technologies = [{
      name: 'C#',
      likes: '0',
      dislikes: '0'
    },
    {
      name: '.Net',
      likes: '0',
      dislikes: '0'
    },
    {
      name: 'Java',
      likes: '0',
      dislikes: '0'
    },
    {
      name: 'MySQL',
      likes: '0',
      dislikes: '0'
    }
  ];

  $scope.incrementlikes = function(technology) {
    technology.likes++;
  }
  $scope.incrementdislikes = function(technology) {
    technology.dislikes++;
  }
  $scope.addRecord = function() {
    var technology = {likes: '0', dislikes: '0'};
    technology.name = $scope.newTechName;
    $scope.technologies.push(technology);
  }
});
```

```css
table,
th,
tr,
td {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  background: #006688;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <table style="width:400px;">
    <tr>
      <td align="right">Enter Technologies : </td>
      <td><input type="text" ng-model=newTechName></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="Add" ng-click="addRecord(technology);" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table style="width:400px;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Likes</th>
        <th>Dislikes</th>
        <th>Likes / Dislikes</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="technology in technologies">
        <td>{{technology.name}}</td>
        <td align="center">{{technology.likes}}</td>
        <td align="center">{{technology.dislikes}}</td>
        <td align="center">
          <input type="button" value="Likes" ng-click="incrementlikes(technology);" />
          <input type="button" value="Dislikes" ng-click="incrementdislikes(technology);" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

please check the below link you can find the solution

$scope.technology = technology.push();//wrong way

$scope.technologies.push(technology)//wright way to push to an array

```
 $scope.addRecord = function() {
var tempTech={
  name: $scope.newtechnology,
  likes: '0',
  dislikes: '0'
}
$scope.technologies.push(tempTech);
}



  <table style="width:400px;">
<tr>
  <td align="right">Enter Technologies : </td>
  <td><input type="text" ng-model="newtechnology" /></td>
  <td><input type="button" value="Add" ng-click="addRecord();" /></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Only a small code fix required in addRecord function. Find the solution below:-

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope){
$scope.technologies = [
  {name:'C#', likes:'0', dislikes:'0'},
  {name:'.Net', likes:'0', dislikes:'0'},
  {name:'Java', likes:'0', dislikes:'0'},
  {name:'MySQL', likes:'0', dislikes:'0'}
  ];

  $scope.incrementlikes = function(technology){
  technology.likes++;
  }
  $scope.incrementdislikes = function(technology){
  technology.dislikes++;
  }
  $scope.addRecord = function(){
  $scope.technologies.push({name:$scope.newTechnology, likes:'0', dislikes:'0'});
  }
});
```

```css
table,
th,
tr,
td {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  background: #006688;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <table style="width:400px;">
    <tr>
      <td align="right">Enter Technologies : </td>
      <td><input type="text" ng-model="newTechnology"/></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="Add" ng-click="addRecord();" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table style="width:400px;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Likes</th>
        <th>Dislikes</th>
        <th>Likes / Dislikes</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="technology in technologies">
        <td>{{technology.name}}</td>
        <td align="center">{{technology.likes}}</td>
        <td align="center">{{technology.dislikes}}</td>
        <td align="center">
          <input type="button" value="Likes" ng-click="incrementlikes(technology);" />
          <input type="button" value="Dislikes" ng-click="incrementdislikes(technology);" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to do below changes to your code.

1. Add **ng-model="techName"** to the text field
2. Change argument of ng-click (**ng-click="addRecord(techName);"**) from "technology" to "techName"(this is ng-model name), it binds text field to this argument.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope){
$scope.technologies = [
  {name:'C#', likes:'0', dislikes:'0'},
  {name:'.Net', likes:'0', dislikes:'0'},
  {name:'Java', likes:'0', dislikes:'0'},
  {name:'MySQL', likes:'0', dislikes:'0'}
  ];

  $scope.incrementlikes = function(technology){
  technology.likes++;
  }
  $scope.incrementdislikes = function(technology){
  technology.dislikes++;
  }
  $scope.addRecord = function(text){
  $scope.technologies.push({name:text, likes:'0', dislikes:'0'});
  }
});
```

```css
table,
th,
tr,
td {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  background: #006688;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <table style="width:400px;">
    <tr>
      <td align="right">Enter Technologies : </td>
      <td><input type="text" ng-model="techName"/></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="Add" ng-click="addRecord(techName);" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table style="width:400px;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Likes</th>
        <th>Dislikes</th>
        <th>Likes / Dislikes</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="technology in technologies">
        <td>{{technology.name}}</td>
        <td align="center">{{technology.likes}}</td>
        <td align="center">{{technology.dislikes}}</td>
        <td align="center">
          <input type="button" value="Likes" ng-click="incrementlikes(technology);" />
          <input type="button" value="Dislikes" ng-click="incrementdislikes(technology);" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```